# Bash : Get multiple values from json processed seperately in a single file

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on getting SSM values by path and adding name and values as pairs in a file.
The json file contains path as name and value is directly represented. I am stripping the path to get only the name, but both of these are in seperate commands and I need to add them in format

```
name=value
```

Example json:

```
   aws ssm   get-parameters-by-path --region eu-central-1 --path /dev/stagefirst/ --with-decryption
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "/dev/stagefirst/param-password",
            "Type": "SecureString",
            "Value": "password",
            "Version": 1,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1601372197.273,
        },
        {
            "Name": "/dev/stagefirst/param-username",
            "Type": "SecureString",
            "Value": "username",
            "Version": 1,
            "LastModifiedDate": 1601372195.764,
        }
    ]
}
```

I am processing name and values in this manner...

```
aws ssm   get-parameters-by-path --region eu-central-1 --path /dev/stagefirst/ --with-decryption | jq -r ".Parameters[].Name" | sed 's:.*/::'
aws ssm   get-parameters-by-path --region eu-central-1 --path /dev/stagefirst/ --with-decryption | jq -r ".Parameters[].Value"
```

The end file would look like this

```
param-username=username
param-password=password
```

How can I combine them? Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this jq.

`jq -r '.Parameters[] | .Name +"="+ .Value' | sed 's:.*/::'`

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq` only on a single call:

```sh
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
  --region eu-central-1 \
  --path /dev/stagefirst/ \
  --with-decryption |
  jq -r '.Parameters[]|((.Name|capture(".*/(?<a>.*)").a+"=")+.Value)'
```

**Using a stand-alone `jq` script to process the output of `aws ssm get-parameters-by-path`**

Create a `jq` script file named `ssmparameters2sh` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -rf

.Parameters[] | (
  (
    .Name |
      capture(".*/param-(?<name>.*)")
      .name
  ) + "=" + (
    .Value | @sh
  )
)
```

Make it executable:

```sh
chmod +x ssmparameters2sh
```

Now use it like this in your script, to have access to the parameters directly converted to variables within the shell:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source <(
  aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
    --region eu-central-1 \
    --path /dev/stagefirst/ \
    --with-decryption |
    ./ssmparameters2sh
)

# Debug display variables declared by
# the dynamically converted and sourced data
typeset -p password username
```

Will output something like:

```sh
declare -- password="password"
declare -- username="username"
```

Now if you have Bash4+ with associative arrays, you can convert the JSON Parameters directly into a Bash's Associative array with a slight modification of the `ssmparameters2sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -jf

"declare -A parameters=(",
(
  .Parameters[] | (
    "[" + (
      .Name |
        capture(".*/(?<name>.*)")
        .name | @sh
    ) + "]=" + (
      .Value | @sh + " "
    )
  )
),
")"
```

And the shell sourcing it is almost same, except it prints the `parameters` associative array declaration for demoing instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source <(
  aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
    --region eu-central-1 \
    --path /dev/stagefirst/ \
    --with-decryption |
    ./ssmparameters2sh
)

# Debug display the parameters associative array
# dynamically converted and sourced from the json data
typeset -p parameters
```

Will output something like:

```sh
declare -A parameters=([param-password]="password" [param-username]="username" )
```

Same as above with an inlined `jq` script to fill the entries of the Associative array declaration:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A parameters="($(
  aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
    --region eu-central-1 \
    --path /dev/stagefirst/ \
    --with-decryption |
    jq -j '.Parameters[]|("["+(.Name|capture(".*/(?<a>.*)").a|@sh)+"]="+(.Value|@sh+" "))'
))"

typeset -p parameters
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Is there a way to get the value and export it, so it's available in the script So, let's say the command output is username=XYZ. I want to call export username=XYZ... so I can just use $username in my script. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg Variables are already provided to the Bash script, so no need to export

Comment: No,  I mean the Name as a key and value from SSM should be exported. Are those values available inside the script?  So, all params which are pulled under /dev/stage/first/, all are exported key-value pairs....where key being the Name after /dev/stage/ and value retrieved. :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg not sure what you want about export. Exporting has a specific meaning within a shell. It means environment variables available to all the processes run (spawned) after that. The script snippet I wrote to you don't need an export, because once it is run, the `username` and `password` variables for the first version or the associative array `parameters` are already made available within the current Bash shell script. Also note about  exporting these to other programs as environment, only the plain string variables `username` and `password` can be exported, the associative array cannot

Comment: I have written a pastebin explaining what I mean : https://pastebin.com/pXNU3PA0   Can you please have a look. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg If you have further questions, please create a new post folowing StackOverflow's [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Neither comments here or an external PasteBin page is appropriate. I am willing to help you but not here.